# Is it possible to develop an XBAP application with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: wpf, xbap

Is it possible to develop an XBAP application with Visual Studio 2019 ? The project template is not shown when creating a new project.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean wpf for the web i think it's limited to visual studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can , The project template named WPF Browser App

[image]

Visual studio 2019 version:
[image]